# Lubuntu 13.10 does not ugrade to 14.04

Tags: 13.10, upgrade, lubuntu, 14.04, update-manager

I'm trying to upgrade to the newest version of Lubuntu, but after I open the software updater, clicking on upgrade, and enter my authentication. The updater just closes and nothing happens. Whenever I try again, the same result occurs. Anyone else experiencing this problem, and/or know how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have already backed up any data that cannot live without.  If you have not do that first.  I think the commands to update from the command line are:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo do-release-upgrade
```